# How to display HTML in Silverlight application?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I would need to display some basic HTML (just some paragraphs, unordered lists and hyperlinks) in my Silverlight application. How would I go about that?

Which control to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this link for starters: http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/12/22/silverlight-4-s-new-html-hosting-support.aspx

Here is the relevant part:

> Another of the new capabilities that Silverlight 4 brings to the
>   platform is the ability to host HTML content inside a Silverlight
>   control. This support isn't limited to static HTML content; the
>   content can be interactive and can include script. It can even be
>   Flash content or content that includes other Silverlight controls.
>
> To host HTML content in Silverlight, you can use either a WebBrowser
>   control or an HtmlBrush. One way to display HTML content is to fire up
>   a WebBrowser control and point it to a URL:

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="WebBrowserControl" Source="http://www.bing.com" />
```

> Another way to do it is to call NavigateToString and pass a string of
>   content to the WebBrowser control:

```
WebBrowserControl.NavigateToString("<h1>Hello, Silverlight</h1>");
```

> HTML hosting is not available to in-browser apps (it applies to
>   out-of-browser applications only), and if an OOB lacks elevated
>   permissions, it can only display content that comes from the same
>   domain as the Silverlight application. However, you can use a little
>   trick to display cross-domain content in OOBs that run without
>   elevated permissions—simply pass an IFRAME targeting the remote
>   content to NavigateToString:

```
WebBrowserControl.NavigateToString("<iframe src=\"http://www.bing.com\" style=\"width: 100%; height: 100%\"></iframe>");
```

> You can render HTML content with HtmlBrush, too. The following XAML
>   snippet paints a Rectangle with content retrieved from Bing:

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="WebBrowserControl" Source="http://www.bing.com" />
<Rectangle>
  <Rectangle.Fill>
    <HtmlBrush SourceName="WebBrowserControl" />
  </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

> One difference between WebBrowser and HtmlBrush is that the former
>   displays "live" content, while the latter does not. Another difference
>   is that HtmlBrush can have transforms applied to it, while WebBrowser
>   cannot. For snazzy visual effects involving HTML content like the HTML
>   puzzle demoed at the PDC, you'll probably find yourself using
>   HtmlBrush. To display live, interactive content, you'll find
>   WebBrowser more useful instead.
>
> One of the really cool things about the WebBrowser control is that you
>   can use its InvokeScript method to call JavaScript functions in
>   content hosted by the control. Conversely, JavaScript hosted inside a
>   WebBrowser control can use window.external.Notify to raise
>   ScriptNotify events that can be handled in C#.

Answer (score 2):

You could use HtmlBrush or webbrowser control.